# Python: flush a buffer before program termination via a finalizer

Tags: python, buffer, destructor, finalizer

I keep a cache of transactions to flush (to persistent storage) on the event of a watermark or object finalization. Since `__del__` is [no longer guaranteed to be called](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__del__#object.__del__) on every object, is the appropriate approach to hook a similar function (or `__del__` itself) into `atexit.register` (during initialization)?

If I'm not mistaken, this *will* cause the object to which the method is bound to hang around until program termination. This isn't likely to be a problem, but maybe there's a more elegant solution?

Note: I know using `__del__` is non-ideal because [it can cause uncatchable exceptions](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__del__#object.__del__), but I can't think of another way to do this short of cascading `finalize()` calls all the way through my program. TIA!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need your object to be alive at the time you perform the flush, you could use [weak references](http://docs.python.org/library/weakref.html)

This is similar to your proposed solution, but rather than using a real reference, store a list of weak references, with a callback function to perform the flush.  This way, the references aren't going to keep those objects alive, and you won't run into any circular garbage problems with `__del__` methods.

You can run through the list of weak references on termination to manually flush any still alive if this needs to be guaranteed done at a certain point.

Comment: I think this is the elegant solution I was looking for -- if an object gets GC'd, I make a callback to the managing class from __del__. If it isn't GC'd, the weak reference must still be present in the managing class at termination, and I can hook an atexit callback to have the managing class flush.

Answer (score 4):

If you have to handle ressources the prefered way is to have an explicit call to a  `close()` or `finalize()` method. Have a look at the `with` statement to abstract that. In your case the `weakref` module might be an option. The cached object can be garbage collected by the system and have their `__del__()` method called or you finalize them if they are still alive.

Comment: You gave the solution before Brian, but he explained it in a little more detail which made it click in my brain. Sorry about that -- I still upvoted yours!

Answer (score 3):

I would say `atexit` or try and see if you can refactor the code into being able to be expressed using a `with_statement` which is in the `__future__` in 2.5 and in 2.6 by default.  2.5 includes a module contextlib to simplify things a bit.  I've done something like this when using Canonical's Storm ORM.

from **future** import with_statement

```
@contextlib.contextmanager
def start_transaction(db):
  db.start()
  yield
  db.end()

with start_transaction(db) as transaction:
  ...
```

For a non-db case, you could just register the objects to be flushed with a global and then use something similar.  The benefit of this approach is that it keeps things explicit.

Answer (score 2):

Put the following in a file called `destructor.py`

```
import atexit

objects = []

def _destructor():
    global objects
    for obj in objects:
        obj.destroy()
    del objects

atexit.register(_destructor)
```

now use it this way:

```
import destructor

class MyObj(object):
    def __init__(self):
        destructor.objects.append(self)
        # ... other init stuff
    def destroy(self):
        # clean up resources here
```

Comment: Module is cool, but I'd vote for a callable class instead of a module with a global.

Comment: @S.Lott: Callables aren't singletons. A module object is. This way I can have many modules using a single destructor module.

Answer (score 0):

I think `atexit` is the way to go here.